# Keep Alive Timer called close() error between jersey servers, using TLS

Tags: rest, web-services, ssl, jersey, tls1.2

I have a multimodule Jersey project, where at some point in serving a request a Gateway module will talk to another Gateway module (this is the "service discovery" part of the communication) on another PC. This communication works well, but when the code execution gets to the next request where these 2 modules talk again (this is still for serving that first request, this is the "negotiation" part of the communication between the gateway modules), the request times out fast with a

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:790)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:647)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:787)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:647)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1534)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1439)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:394)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:285)
    ... 38 more
```

I use the `-Djavax.net.debug=SSL` VM argument to see what's happening, and both gateways print the same log:

```
Keep-Alive-Timer, called close()
Keep-Alive-Timer, called closeInternal(true)
Keep-Alive-Timer, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
Keep-Alive-Timer, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 64
Keep-Alive-Timer, called closeSocket(true)
grizzly-nio-kernel(4) SelectorRunner, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 64
grizzly-nio-kernel(4) SelectorRunner, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, close_notify
grizzly-nio-kernel(4) SelectorRunner, closeInboundInternal()
grizzly-nio-kernel(4) SelectorRunner, closeOutboundInternal()
grizzly-nio-kernel(4) SelectorRunner, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
grizzly-nio-kernel(4) SelectorRunner, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 64
```

This time the code execution does not reach my code on the receiver gateway. Each HTTP request I send in these modules, a new `javax.ws.rs.client.Client` is built and used. Both gateway requests have the exact same `javax.ws.rs.client.Client` configuration (same connect/read timeout, same SSL context, same hostnameverifier), only the path and payload is different, I'm not trying to keep connections open at all, since this is a REST application.

I cant find anything useful on the net for `Keep-Alive-Timer, called close()`, but I assume this is the TLS keep alive function, since this communication works well without TLS, on normal HTTP. What could be the problem? I can provide more detail if needed.